# Showing / modifying the query for an MsExchDynamicDistributionList exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

How does one show or modify the query for an `MsExchDynamicDistributionList` in Powershell / Exchange Management Console or the GUI?

I've found the query I need to read or modify, but I haven't been able see the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, unless you really are asking something that simplistic as to double click on the distro list in the console and then modify the query.

Maybe this article will help:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124560%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

Maybe updating your post with a screenshot of the DL in question in the EMC GUI would help if this isn't the case, but normally you just open the properties of the group and click on the `Conditions` tab.

Comment: Ah okay it's on the `filters` tab... thanks!